# Setup Magento2 Docker Config Apple Silicon M1

Tags: magento2, docker, environment-emulation

is there any way to set up a docker compatible environment for Apple M1? Unfortunately Warden doesn't support the new ARM chips for now.
are there any viable alternatives to having a working development stack?

Comment: rebuild all your containers with ARM images.

Comment: Hello! Did you get this to work by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this docker for magento 2 on Apple Silicon.

https://github.com/luancschmitz/docker-magento-mac-m1

Comment: This repo is discontinued. 
Updated one: https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento